# Assumption on SuccessiveShortestPaths

Tags: graphs, network-flow

I read that one assumption for Successive Shortest Paths algorithm for computing the minimum cost flow problem is that every cost is non-negative.

I also read that this assumption can be removed with proper network transformations, what are those?

I found on some notes this:

[image]

Where $ c(u\rightarrow v)  $ is the capacity of arc from u to v and $ \\\$ (u\rightarrow v)$ is the cost of arc from u to v.

I can't get the logic behind the transformation proposed, any help is appreciated.